# IndexError on Raspberry pi 3b+ but not in pc Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, index-error

I am writing a program that sends me a specific number from a website to my phone. When I run the Python file on my laptop it runs smoothly but when I run it on my Raspberry Pi I get this error

```
Pillen_ant = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name("bg_periode.vandaag")[1].text
IndexError: list index out of range
```

But it is not, I use the same line of code on my laptop and then it works fine.

Comment: From just looking at the piece of code, I feel like you are trying to do web scraping. So when you are using your Raspberry Pi, the website seems to not be creating the element with the class name `bg_periode.vandaag`, hence the index error. If I were you, I would first find out why that element on the website is showing up.

Answer (score 0):

The call

```
self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name("bg_periode.vandaag")
```

is not returning a list with 2 elements when you run it on the Pi. When you try to index into it at element `[1]` it is failing because the list doesn't have that many elements. Try adding a breakpoint in your code right before that line and then inspect it by hand to see what is being returned.

Comment: I've just tried this but is does not help. When I add the breakpoint and I search the element I have to type in "bg_periode vandaag" In my code I said this as "bg_periode.vandaag" otherwise it will not find an element at al. But it is the right name to find the element. When I search the name with inspect than I find 2 elements.

Comment: to clarify, add the breakpoint, then use the "next" or "step" commands to advance the program. Also, first remove the `[1]` and everything after it. You can do that separately if you'd like, but you need to get the result of `find_elements_by_class_name("bg_periode.vandaag")`, by itself stored in a variable, so you can look at it before trying to index into it.